# WHY DOSENT MY SERVER START WHEN I RUN node server.js in the folder my server.js file is saved into

Tags: node.js, command-prompt

I just started learning api development with `nodejs`, however, my node server wont start when i run `node server.js`. It doesn't display any errors.

Here is a [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpHTj.png)

Here is the server.js file

```
const http = require('http');
const app = require('./app')

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(PORT);
```

Comment: did you try to ping your server, do http://localhost:3000 in browser.

Comment: You will need to show some more code. What is in the contents of the `app.js` you are requiring?

Comment: also checnge server.listen(port) to this server.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('server listening on port: ',port);
}); it will log if server is running

Comment: You need to show the code of `./app` before we can say anything. But if we consider your `app = express()` then it will work fine.

Comment: Thank you all for responding, I just ran `node server.js` on my console and it worked, without changing a single line. I don't know why